# Why do I get a "type annotations needed" error creating a notify watcher?

Tags: rust

```
let mut watcher = notify::recommended_watcher(|res: Result<_>| {
    match res {
       Ok(event) => {
            match event.kind {
                EventKind::Modify(ModifyKind::Metadata(_)) => { /* deal with metadata */ }
                EventKind::Create(CreateKind::File) => { /* deal with new files */ }
                EventKind::Other => { /* ignore meta events */ }
                _ => { /* something else changed */ }
            }
        },
        Err(e) => println!("watch error: {:?}", e)
    }
})
```

This code block gives me the error:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:13:23
   |
13 |                 match event.kind {
   |                       ^^^^^ cannot infer type
```

[Rust Explorer](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#%2F*%0A%5Bdependencies%5D%0Anotify%20%3D%20%225%22%0A*%2F%0A%0Ause%20notify%3A%3Aevent%3A%3A%7BCreateKind%2C%20EventKind%2C%20ModifyKind%7D%3B%0Ause%20notify%3A%3AResult%3B%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20watcher%20%3D%20notify%3A%3Arecommended_watcher(%7Cres%3A%20Result%3C_%3E%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20match%20res%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ok(event)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20match%20event.kind%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20EventKind%3A%3AModify(ModifyKind%3A%3AMetadata(_))%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%2F*%20deal%20with%20metadata%20*%2F%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20EventKind%3A%3ACreate(CreateKind%3A%3AFile)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%2F*%20deal%20with%20new%20files%20*%2F%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20EventKind%3A%3AOther%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%2F*%20ignore%20meta%20events%20*%2F%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20_%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%2F*%20something%20else%20changed%20*%2F%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Err(e)%20%3D%3E%20println!(%22watch%20error%3A%20%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20e)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0A)

Which doesn't make sense to me because the docs for notify use the same code without specifying a type in the match.

Can anyone help explain what is going on and where I should specify which type to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many layers of indirection for Rust to infer what type the `_` placeholder in `Result<_>` refers to. It will compile if you tell it `_` means `Event`:

```
use notify::Event;

let mut watcher = notify::recommended_watcher(|res: Result<Event>| {
    match res {
       Ok(event) => {
            match event.kind {
                EventKind::Modify(ModifyKind::Metadata(_)) => { /* deal with metadata */ }
                EventKind::Create(CreateKind::File) => { /* deal with new files */ }
                EventKind::Other => { /* ignore meta events */ }
                _ => { /* something else changed */ }
            }
        },
        Err(e) => println!("watch error: {:?}", e)
    }
})
```

[Rust Explorer](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#%2F*%0A%5Bdependencies%5D%0Anotify%20%3D%20%225%22%0A*%2F%0A%0Ause%20notify%3A%3Aevent%3A%3A%7BCreateKind%2C%20EventKind%2C%20ModifyKind%7D%3B%0Ause%20notify%3A%3A%7BEvent%2C%20Result%7D%3B%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20watcher%20%3D%20notify%3A%3Arecommended_watcher(%7Cres%3A%20Result%3CEvent%3E%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20match%20res%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ok(event)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20match%20event.kind%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20EventKind%3A%3AModify(ModifyKind%3A%3AMetadata(_))%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%2F*%20deal%20with%20metadata%20*%2F%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20EventKind%3A%3ACreate(CreateKind%3A%3AFile)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%2F*%20deal%20with%20new%20files%20*%2F%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20EventKind%3A%3AOther%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%2F*%20ignore%20meta%20events%20*%2F%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20_%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%2F*%20something%20else%20changed%20*%2F%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Err(e)%20%3D%3E%20println!(%22watch%20error%3A%20%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20e)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0A)

The layers of indirection are:

1. The argument to `recommended_watcher` must be a type that implements `EventHandler`:

   ```
   pub fn recommended_watcher<F>(event_handler: F) -> Result<RecommendedWatcher> 
   where
       F: EventHandler,
   ```
2. A single-argument function that takes a `Result<Event>` and returns nothing is an `EventHandler`:

   ```
   impl<F> EventHandler for F
   where
       F: FnMut(Result<Event>) + Send + 'static,
   ```
3. Therefore `Result<_>` must be `Result<Event>` to match the signature `FnMut(Result<Event>)`.